To which services or resource Azure Workbooks can be linked to
Is there any way to know exactly to which services and resources can I link the workbooks to?
I know that this can be tied to monitor, advisor but I would like to have a full list of this information.
I went through the documentation with no success.

Azure workbooks can pull data from multiple sources across Azure to visualize and analyze telemetry, logs, and metrics. Workbooks are primarily tied to Azure Monitor but extend to a wide range of services that expose data via metrics, logs, or APIs.
As per this MS Doc and this Doc I can see it can be linked to-


